# Display realtime date and time in ionic 5

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, real-time, standards

I am trying to display real time date and time on my Ionic mobile apps. Turns out current coding is not in real time, need to refresh every time to see correct time every seconds and minutes.
And I also wish it to be like the standard time not as in the user's device time. Please advise.

Current coding that I use is

`public today : number  = Date.now();`

```
<ion-title size="small" slot="end">{{ today | date: 'medium' }}</ion-title>
```

Answer (score 3):

// .ts file

```
today = new Date();
```

constructor

```
constructor() {    
this.startTime();}
```

function

```
startTime() {
var intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
  this.today = new Date().toISOString();
}.bind(this),500)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something refreshing the time for you. Typically it is a running setInterval method:

```
setInterval(this.refreshTime, 1000); // this will call refreshTime every second
```

Now your refreshTime method should update your "today" property value and change detection will do the rest:

```
refreshTime() {

    this.today = Date.now()

}
```

*Depending on how you are using this, you need to make sure inside ngOnDestroy() hook you remove the intervals to prevent memory leaks. See examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Examples)*

Comment: Not really what I want but useful and helpful for my code.

Comment: But the app uses the device clock, what if I want the app to use the standard time? for example as in [link](http://mst.sirim.my/)

Comment: what do you mean by standard time? the link provided implementation likely uses the same approach i described above

Comment: I mean when I change the device's clock, the app's clock changes too and the time  is easily manipulated